# Why does Smooth Tool break my Model?

Tags: sculpting, smooth

I have been following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsnzMZve_NU&list=PL5E60-kf6-wO6_z95Ri1y3LMclKL8pQJt&index=3&t=145s):

When I try finally reach the sculpting mode @[4:30](https://youtu.be/HsnzMZve_NU?t=268), and use the Smooth tool, it immediately starts to break my whole model and eat it up.

[image]

Also, my cubes or voxels are really huge and not as small @[2:56](https://youtu.be/HsnzMZve_NU?t=176). Maybe that's why I'm not able to sculpt and my model breaks while using the Smooth tool?

[image]

Comment: You need to Apply the remesh modifier first.

Comment: It is after the remesh modifier only that I start the sculpting and then this happens >.< Ive followed all steps correctly !

Comment: She applied the modifier at arround 4 minutes mark, you just missed that part =)